# Updating Parent Form from Child with Threads

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a little puzzled on how to go about this problem.

I have a parent form that contains a DataGridView, and a child form which is used to enter some details for account creation.

On the account creation form, when the user creates an account it launches a thread that goes and registers the account at the website. Each time an account is created I want to:

1) Add it to the database. I assume this is as simple as creating a connection and inserting it. Can that be done from the child form? i.e. is the database accessible globally?

2) Update the dataGridView on the parent form?

It's important to note that the child form is called using form.showDialog() which I presume makes updating the parent form impossible? Should I use form.show()?

What's the conventional way of doing what I want to achieve?

Thanks

Comment: All you need is a reference to the parent form in your sub-form.  Make a private class variable for your sub-form of whatever type your parent form is.  When you create this form, use a set method to set the parent form.  You should be able to update the grid from that.

Comment: You can Achieve the communications using Delgates if you want to use that.

Answer (score 2):

Your database access is not limited to one specific form - so yes, you can do the database insert from the child form.  Like DOTNETBEE said, you can update the parent form by using delegates:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AccountForm objAccountForm = new AccountForm();
        objAccountForm.CreateAccount+= new ChangeStatusHandler(objAccountForm_CreateAccount);
        objAccountForm.Show();
    }
    public void objAccountForm_CreateAccount(string accountName)
    {
        //Add account to grid.
    }
}

public delegate void CreateAccountHandler(string accountName);
public partial class AccountForm: Form
{
    public event CreateAccountHandler CreateAccount;

    public AccountForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        //Create your account.
        ...
        if (CreateAccount!= null)
        {
            CreateAccount(txtAccountName.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to return more than the account name, just change the CreateAccountHandler signature to return the account class or create an EventArgs class with all the properties you require.

If creating the account can take a long time and you need to do it on a thread, use a BackGroundWorker and then call the CreateAccount delegate in the callback method in stead of in the button click event.